# Second isomorphism theorem proof for groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

I'd like to be prove the second isomorphism theorem.

> Let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of $G$ with $K$ normal in $G$. The subgroup $H \cap K$ is normal in $H$, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $K$ is normal in $HK$.
>
> We want to show that $\frac{H}{H \cap K}$ and $\frac{HK}{K}$ are isomorphic using the map:
>
> $$f: \frac{H}{H \cap K} \rightarrow \frac{HK}{K} $$
> $$ : \overline{h} \rightarrow \overline{h \cdot 1}$$

**My attempt**:

$H \cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, so the quotient $\frac{H \cap K}{H}$
is a group. Second, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$,
therefore $\frac{HK}{K}$ is also a group. So, the map $f$ is well-defined.


Let $x,y \in \frac{H}{H \cap K}$.

\begin{equation*}
    f(\overline{xy}) = \overline{xy\cdot1} = \overline{x \cdot 1 \cdot y \cdot 1}
    = \overline{x \cdot 1} \overline{y \cdot 1}
    = f(\overline{x})f(\overline{y})
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $f$ is a group-homomorphism. Besides,

\begin{align*}
    \text{ker}(f) &= \left\{
        \overline{h} \in \frac{H}{H \cap K}: f(\overline{h}) = e_{HK/K}
    \right\} \\
    %
    &= \left\{
        \overline{h} \in \frac{H}{H \cap K}: \overline{h \cdot 1} = e_{HK/K}
    \right\} \\
    %
    &= \left\{
        \overline{h} \in \frac{H}{H \cap K}: \overline{h} \cdot \overline{1} = e_{HK/K}
    \right\} \\
    %
    &= \left\{
        \overline{h} \in \frac{H}{H \cap K}: \overline{h} = e_{HK/K}
    \right\}
\end{align*}

So, $f$ is injective. But I'm stuck for the surjectivity. Any ideas?

Comment: See the posts here at this site. e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463292/questions-about-2nd-isomorphism-theorem?rq=1). There are several good answers given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about 2nd isomorphism theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463292/questions-about-2nd-isomorphism-theorem)

Comment: @Shaun I know this proof but I am asked to prove it specifically using the mapping $f$ defined above. I'd like to know if so far my proof is correct. And if you have any hints/ideas for the surjectivity, I'm willing to take it ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\overline{h\cdot 1}$.

Comment: Hint: $hkK=hK$.